# Java: function to round away from zero?

Tags: java, rounding

How do I round a double away from zero in Java?

The operations I know don't do what I want:

- Casting it to `(int)` rounds it toward zero. `(int) 3.7` will be `3`,
  `(int) - 3.9` will be `-3`.
- `Math.floor()` rounds toward minus infinity. `Math.floor(3.7)` will be `3.0`, `Math.floor(-3.9)` will be `-4.0`.
- `Math.ceil()` rounds toward plus infinity. `Math.ceil(3.7)` will be `4.0`, `Math.ceil(-3.9)` will be `-3.0`.
- `Math.round()` rounds toward the nearest integer.

However I don't have something that rounds away from zero, such that `3.7` becomes `4.0`, and `-3.9` becomes `-4.0`.

Is there such a function in Java?

Comment: Well asked, good research and examples.

Comment: In your example with floor you refer to ceil, and with ceil, you refer to floor.

Answer (score 7):

Check the sign of the number:

```
double roundedAway = (num >= 0) ? Math.ceil(num) : Math.floor(num)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either implement your own function, based on your number being positive or negative, or you can use a [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html). It can round explicitly away from zero with [UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#UP)

It might look something like this

```java
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
System.out.println(df.format(number_here));
```

Comment: This converts the double to a `String`, rather than keeping it as a double. If that's what happens to the double anyway, fine; but you otherwise have to parse it back from the string.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) and [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
double roundAway(double value) {
    return new BigDecimal(value).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).doubleValue();
}
```

Note: this will convert the `double` to a `BigDecimal` with the precise value of the double. To avoid this, you could use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` instead of the constructor which would use the canonical string representation of the double, but since you're about to round it to a whole number, this would involve an unnecessary conversion to a string. See the [constructor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)) for more details.